# Assign dynamic div id from js var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble selecting a `div` with jQuery after assigning the `id` to a Javascript variable:

```
$(function() {
    $(".do").live("click",function() 
        {

        var id = $(this).attr("id");

        $.ajax({
           //reload div using js var id 
           $('id').fadeOut('fast').load('http://example.com/get.php').fadeIn("slow");

            });

        return false;
            });
});
```

When I call a static div it works just fine like this:

```
$('#staticdiv').fadeOut('fast').load('http://example.com/get.php').fadeIn("slow");
```

How can I select a `div` from a Javascript variable containing its `id`?

*EDIT
Here is an example if the divs:

 Button to engage reload

```
<a href="" class="do" id="12">click to reload</a>
```

DIV to reload:

```
<div id="12">to be refreshed</div>
```

keep in mind the "12" us dynamic and could be any variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using this:

```
$("#"+id).fadeOut() // ...
```

However, I wouldn't recommend doing it that way (it won't work on things without IDs); try this instead (which should work on things without IDs):

```
$(".do").live("click", function() {
    var me = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: function(data) {
            me.fadeOut('fast').load('http://example.com/get.php').fadeIn("slow");
        }
        // ...
    });
    return false;
});
```

Additionally, I'm not sure if you really want that `.fadeOut().load().fadeIn()` chain; the `load` will not wait for the `fadeOut` to finish and the `fadeIn` will not wait for the `load` to finish (although the `fadeIn` *will* wait for the `fadeOut` to finish). If you have problems with that, you should try this:

```
me.fadeOut('fast', function() {
    me.load('http://www.example.com/get.php', function() {
        me.fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: when i tried `$("#"+id).fadeOut() // ...` it refreshed into the parent div that sent the do() rather than the specific div.  also the alternative/better example you gave would have the same result, loading `$(this);` would just reload in the div where the button is clicked, no?

Comment: @cjaredrun: Does the `div` you want to reload have the `do` class or is it the parent that has the `do` class? If the parent has the `do` class, then you should change the selector from `.do` to `.do > div`.

Comment: i edited post with the div info i am working with and the way i activate `.do`.

Comment: @cjaredrun: It's invalid for two elements to have the same `id`. jQuery (in the first case) may be getting stuck because of that. (the second case explicitly will select the button with no ambiguity in your case)

Comment: in that case, i switch the `href` element from `id` to `name`? i attempted that, with the same result.

Comment: @cjaredrun: Maybe try something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/vfTLq/) (not a complete example).

Comment: that appears to be the ticket. appreciate the guidance @icktoofay.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you supposed to use the variable `id` instead of string `'id'`.

As follows:

```
$('#'+id).fadeOut('fast').load('http://example.com/get.php').fadeIn("slow");
```